# React Component doesn't change states until file is resaved, then runs both at same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a React component piano that was working fine until I messed with the creation of the piano from in the return statement to in a useEffect like I should. Now when I set any states (specifically I am doing it in a useEffect), and then print it out seconds later, it is at the default state. If I then make changes to the component and save, it hot refreshes, and then when I print out the state, one print is from the old line which prints empty still, and one is from the new line which prints the expected newly set state. By new and old line, I mean if I inspect the prints from devtools, one leads me to the old file and one to the new. I have Schrodinger's component... I will dump the entire components code, however the important 3 lines are:
initialize test state on line 69, set_test to 'hello' on line 112, and print test on line 135 on keypress. Below is prints in devtools
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxlb2.png)

**Piano Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import PianoKey from './PianoKey'
import { Howl } from 'howler'
import './Piano.css'
import { attribute_animation, default_ajax } from '../../utility/CommonFunctions'
import { FaXmark } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { MdOutlineSaveAlt } from "react-icons/md";
import { TbShare2 } from "react-icons/tb";
import { IoMdCheckmark } from "react-icons/io";
import { FaPlay, FaPause } from "react-icons/fa";



const Piano = ({ start=12, end=60, type='', set_product=null, visible=true, user_interact=true, song_prop=null }) => {
  
  // Recording START
  let [recording, set_recording] = useState([false, 0])
  let [recorded_song, set_recorded_song] = useState([[], []])
  let [save_prompt, set_save_prompt] = useState([false, false])

  let recording_action = (action) => {
    if (action === 'start') {
      set_recording(prev_state => {
        let rec_arr = [...prev_state]
        rec_arr[0] = true
        return rec_arr
      })

      console.log("recording")
    } else if (action === 'end') {
      console.log("stopped recording")

      // if second recording
      if (recording[1] === 1) {

        if (type == 'register') {
          set_product(recorded_song)
        }
        set_recorded_song([[], []])
      } else {
        if (type == 'login') {
          set_product(recorded_song[0])
          set_recorded_song([[], []])
        } else if (type == 'register') {
          set_recording([false, 1])
        } else {
          set_recording([false, 0])
          set_save_prompt(prev_state => [true, false])
        }
        
      }
    }
  }
  let clear_song = () => {
    set_recorded_song([], [])
    set_recording([false, 0])
  }
  // Recording END

  // Create Piano START
  

  let piano_keys_ref = useRef({})

  let [pressed_keys, set_pressed_keys] = useState(Array(piano_keys_ref.current.length).fill(false))
  let [playback_visual, set_playback_visual] = useState(Array(piano_keys_ref.current.length).fill(''))
  let [key_to_key, set_key_to_key] = useState({})
  let [piano, set_piano] = useState([])
  let [test, set_test] = useState ()


  useEffect(() => {
    // create piano
    // let notes = ['C', 'Db', 'D', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'Gb', 'G', 'Ab', 'A', 'Bb', 'B']
    // let keyboard_keys = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', 
    //                   'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', 
    //                   'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', "'", 'enter',
    //                   'l_shft', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', 'r_shft']
    
    // for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {

    //   if (i-start >= keyboard_keys.length)
    //     break

    //   let note = notes[(i % 12)] + (1+Math.floor(i / 12)).toString()

    //   set_piano(prev_state => {
    //     const new_piano = [
    //       ...prev_state,
    //       <PianoKey 
    //         note={note} 
    //         color={notes[(i % 12)].length === 1 ? 'white' : 'black'} 
    //         keyboard_key={keyboard_keys[i-start]}
    //         key={note}
    //         innerRef={ref => piano_keys_ref.current[i] = ref}
    //         recorded_song={recorded_song}
    //         set_recorded_song={set_recorded_song}
    //         recording={recording}
    //         pressed={pressed_keys[i]}
    //         user_interact={user_interact}
    //         playback_visual={playback_visual[i-start]}
    //       />
    //     ]

    //     // set_key_to_key(prev_state => ({
    //     //   ...prev_state,
    //     //   [keyboard_keys[i-start]]: i-start
    //     // }))
    //     return new_piano;
    //   });
    // 
    set_test('hello')

    return () => {
      set_key_to_key({})
      set_pressed_keys(Array(piano_keys_ref.current.length).fill(false))
      set_piano([])
    }
  }, [])

  // Create Piano END

  // Keyboard Listener START
  const play_piano_key = (event) => {

    let pressed_key = event.key.toLowerCase();

    if (pressed_key === 'shift') {
      pressed_key = event.location === 1 ? 'l_shft': 'r_shft'
    }


    let key_state = event.type === 'keydown'
    let key_ind = key_to_key[pressed_key]
    console.log(test)
    set_pressed_keys(prev_state => ({
      ...prev_state,
      [key_ind]: key_state
    }))
    // set_piano(prev_state => {
    //   const keys = [...prev_state]; 
    //   console.log(keys, key_ind)
    //   keys[key_ind] = React.cloneElement(keys[key_ind], { pressed: key_state }); // Clone the specific PianoKey element and update the pressed prop
    //   return keys; 
    // });
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (user_interact && visible) {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', play_piano_key)
      document.addEventListener('keyup', play_piano_key)
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', play_piano_key)
      document.addEventListener('keyup', play_piano_key)
    };
  }, [visible])
  // Keyboard Listener END


  // Switch 1/2 piano layers START
  let [piano_styling, set_piano_styling] = useState(null)


  const [window_size, setwindow_size] = useState({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setwindow_size({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      });
    };

    // Listen for window resize events
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    // Clean up the event listener
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window_size['width'] >= 1000) {
      set_piano_styling(prev_state => ({
        first_level: {
          width: '50%',
          bottom: '0',
          left: '0'
        },
        second_level: {
          width: '50%',
          bottom: '0',
          right: '0'
        }
      }))
    } else {
      set_piano_styling(null)
    }
  }, [window_size])

  // Switch 1/2 piano layers END

  let save_song = async () => {
    set_save_prompt(async prev_state => {
      let res = await default_ajax('post', 'songs/create-song', { 'song': recorded_song[0], 'name': 'TODO' })
      if (res !== -1) {
        console.log(res)
      }
      return [true, true]
    })
  }

  // Playback START
  let [playing, set_playing] = useState(null)
  let [song, set_song] = useState(song_prop)
  let [playback_index, set_playback_index] = useState(0)
  let song_player = useRef(null)

  function song_playback() {
    let start_time = null;
    let animation_frame_id = null;

    function animate(timestamp) {
      if (!start_time) {
        start_time = timestamp;
      }

      for (let i = playback_index; i < song.length; i++) {
        if (song[i]['start_timestamp'] <= timestamp) {
          let pkey_index = key_to_key[song[i]['note']]
          set_playback_visual(prev_state => {
            let l =[...prev_state]
            l[pkey_index] = 'expand_up'
          })
        } else if (song[i]['end_timestamp'] <= timestamp) {
          let pkey_index = key_to_key[song[i]['note']]
          set_playback_visual(prev_state => {
            let l =[...prev_state]
            l[pkey_index] = 'move_up'
          })
          set_playback_index(prev_state => prev_state + 1)
          }
        }
  
      if (playing) {
        animation_frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    }
  
    function pause() {
      set_playing(false)
      cancelAnimationFrame(animation_frame_id);
    }
  
    function resume() {
        set_playing(true)
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  
    function reset() {
      start_time = null;
      set_playback_index(0)
      set_playing(false)
    }
    return { pause, resume, reset };
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    set_song(song_prop)
    // console.log(song_prop.song_notes)
  }, [song_prop])

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (playing === null) {
      song_player.current = song_playback()
    } else if (playing) {
      console.log('Play')
      song_player.current.resume()
    } else {
      console.log('stop')
      song_player.current.pause()
    }
  }, [playing])

  return (
    <>
      {save_prompt[0] && 
        <div className='piano-saveprompt-screen' onClick={() => set_save_prompt([false, false])}>
          
          <div className='piano-saveprompt' onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} >
            <button className='close-btn' onClick={() => set_save_prompt([false, false])}><FaXmark /></button>
              {save_prompt[0] && !save_prompt[1] && <h2>Save or Share Your Recording</h2>}
              {save_prompt[0] && !save_prompt[1] &&
              <div>
                <button className='piano-saveprompt-btn' onClick={() => save_song()} ><MdOutlineSaveAlt /> Save </button>
                <button className='piano-saveprompt-btn'><TbShare2 /> Share</button>
              </div>
              }
              {save_prompt[0] && save_prompt[1] &&
              <div>
                <div className='pianosave-checkmark' >Saved! <IoMdCheckmark /></div>
                <button>Click here to go to thingy</button>
              </div>
              }

          </div>
        </div>
      }
      
      <div id='piano-wrapper'>
        {user_interact && 
          <div id='piano-btn-wrapper'>
            <button className='piano-btn' onClick={() => recording[0] ? recording_action('end') : recording_action('start')} ><div className='red-dot'></div></button>
            {recording[0] && <button className='piano-btn' id='clear-song-btn' onClick={() => clear_song()} ><FaXmark /></button>}
            {(type === 'register' || type === 'login') && !recording && <p>{recording[1] === 0 ? 'Press Start To Begin Recording' : 'Confirm Password'}</p>}
          </div>
        }
        { type == 'playback' && song &&
          <div id='pianoplayback-btn-wrapper'>
            <button className='piano-btn' onClick={() => set_playing(prev_state => {return prev_state === null ? true : !prev_state})}>{playing ? <FaPause />: <FaPlay /> }</button>
            <button className='piano-btn'>Go to start</button>
          </div>
        }

        

        <div id='piano'>
          <div id="first-level" style={piano_styling ? piano_styling['first_level']: undefined}>
            {piano.length === end-start && piano.slice(0, Math.floor(piano.length/2))}
          </div>
          <div id="second-level" style={piano_styling ? piano_styling['second_level']: undefined}>
            {piano.length === end-start && piano.slice(Math.floor(piano.length/2), piano.length)}
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Piano
```

I've tried messing with the setting of the states, but at the point of setting a simple test state to 'hello' and it not working, I'm at a loss. I have tried resetting the server

Answer (score 0):

I believe I now understand what the problem is. When I set the state of test in an empty useEffect, it correctly updated the value, however, the way I was printing it (through event listeners in another useEffect) was faulty. The event listeners called a function, and because of the way JS closures work, the function was only referencing the state from the time it initialized. This led to it always being undefined. I am still a little confused on why it was printing twice, one with the old value and one with the new, because I don't think React usually remounts the application on file save, but I guess that's what happened. I also don't know why the second print statement captured the correct value of the test state as a remount should have led to the exact same fault behavior

Comment: You need to look into the way `useEffect()` works.  It mounts on frame rendering, not at all in the way you might be used to in JavaScript.  You also don't have anything in the dependency array.  Post your updated code and I can probably make more suggestions.